# How to sort through two merged collections that have different models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models `Cities` and `States`. One `City` has 1 `State` and one `State` can have 0 or more `Cities`. I need to retrieve all `Cities` and `States` separately because I need to display states even if a state has no related cities (like Alabama in the below example). The issue is I need to sort by State name first, and than by Cities in that state (if there are any)

Cities

```
id, state_id, name 
1, 1, San Diego 
2, 1, Hollywood
3, 2, Seattle
4, 3, Pheonix
```

States

```
id, name
1, California
2, Washington 
3, Arizona
4, Alabama
```

Controller:

```php
$cities = Cities::with('state')->get(); // Returns the state relationship 
$states = States::get();

$merged = $states->merge($cities);
```

I would now like to sort by `State` name first, and then all the cities in that `State` and return a merged collection similar to this:

```json
{
    id: 4,
    name: Alabama,
}, 
{
    id: 3,
    name: Arizona,
}, 
{
    id: 3,
    name: Pheonix,
    state_id: 3
    state: {
        id: 3,
        name: Arizona
    }
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: California
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: Hollywood
    state_id: 1,
    state: {
        id: 1,
        name: California
    }
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: San Diego,
    state_id: 1,
    state: {
        id: 1,
        name: California
    }
}, 
{
    id: 2,
    name: Washington,

},
{
    id: 2,
    name: Seattle,
    state_id: 2,
    state: {
        id: 2,
        name: Washington
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do a query like this:

```
$states = State::all()->sortBy('name'); // Here your sort by the state name first
```

If you made the relations right you can access the cities from each state like this: (you dont need to merge collections):

```
@foreach($states as $state)  // this will sort the cities by id
{{$state->cities}}
@endforeach
```

To sort them by the name you could try this:

```
@foreach($states as $state)  
{{$state->cities->sortBy('name')}}
@endforeach
```